# (evil-scroll-up COUNT) not working in Spacemacs

Tags: key-bindings, evil, scrolling

I am trying to make this shortcut work:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<s-C-M-S-return>") '(evil-scroll-up 8))
```

But it is not working.

If I remove the COUNT:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<s-C-M-S-return>") 'evil-scroll-up)
```

it is working. However, it is jumping by half-pages and I want to specify the number of lines to scroll.

How to do that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got something similar[1] working by using a wrapper function.

```
(defun my/evil-up-by-eight ()
    (interactive)
    (evil-scroll-up 8))

(global-set-key (kbd "<C-M-return>") 'my/evil-up-by-eight)
```

---

[1] I couldn't emulate that specific key binding, so I just used Ctrl + Meta + Ret instead.

Comment: It seems like it works only with (interactive). This is very confusing to me, because sometimes you se interactive and sometimes you don't in these examples even in the manual.